# How i can delete the number of push notification by the app-icon as programmer?

Tags: iphone, numbers, xamarin, push

I want to delete the number (of push notifiactions by the app-icon) by starting the app.

How i can resolve this?

I use the XAMARIN Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```